# open image full screen with "open -a Preview"

Tags: macos, command-line, preview

Using osx 10.9.3

I would like to write a script that opens images full-screen with preview but I can't seem to find the command line options for the Preview application.

Answer (score 9):

Preview.app doesn't have command line options, but you could use AppleScript in Terminal:

```
open -a Preview somefile.png ; /usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "Preview"' -e "activate" -e 'tell application "System Events"' -e 'keystroke "f" using {control down, command down}' -e "end tell" -e "end tell"
```

Just replace `somefile.png` with the path/image you want; AppleScript invokes fullscreen.

Comment: this is nice but can you make it as variable for file names so it has not to be done manually each time

Comment: Are you meaning `f=$"somefile.png" ; open -a Preview $f ...`?